# jQuery UI wont work in firefox with duplicate code as demo

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, gallery

http://ecefx-dev.com/skribble/ works fine in Chrome (I'm talking about the top slider where you click and drag the scrollbar).

In firefox/IE though it keeps breaking. If you look at console while you click scrollbar you will see the problem (??)

So far I have
-used identical version of jquery, jquery UI, and ui.slider as the demo, yet the demo works fine in firefox. http://www.ericdubois.com/jquery_tests/slider_gallery3.php

I even copied/pasted their code directly, including the scripts mentioned above. The only one i didnt do is jquery but the build number matches so its exact. The one thing is that I changed, at the bottom of ui.slider there is a bit of code that uses $ and I changed it to jQuery because I'm using Wordpress.

the css is 90% the same except for a background image, and the html uses all the same classes, except my html has a div inside an li instead of just an image.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any errors in the console in Firefox. What exactly are you seeing?

Comment: http://imgur.com/vdyQC - and when you click and drag nothing happens, it doesnt move nor do the images go. Also, you can see the images are on two lines so something isn't registering like it should (I think the ul should have a very large width). This also happens in IE. Im using FF 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner UL is collapsing in Firefox causing its list items to display on two lines, causing the itemsWidth to become -15.

Change the following and it should work:

```
.sliderGallery ul li {
display: inline-block;
*display: inline; // IE7
zoom: 1; // IE7
}
```

and remove float-left on .event-img

Answer (score 1):

It's your configuration. The value you pass in itemsWidth for the max value comes out to be 0 on Firefox.

Comment: where do i change said configuration?